# Which is the right design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

I need some advice on which design pattern to use for the problem at hand.

I want to write a library allowing to retrieve external-data from some source (a local file, from the web, ...) and make this data accessible via an interface. The datasets are diverse and possibly change on case-by-case basis (e.g. population counts, weather-data, ...).

So extensibility and easy-maintenance is important.

I am thinking to use the Bridge pattern here. Is it a good choice?
Haven't written code yet, just figuring out the best design.

Any help is much appreciated!
Cheers /S

```
class DataSource 
{
protected:
   DataSrcImpl* _impl;

public:
   DataSource(DataSrcImpl* arg) : _impl(arg) {};

   virtual void retrieveData() = 0;
}

class PopulationDataSource : public DataSource
{
private:
   // members to store data

public:
   PopulationDataSource(DataSrcImpl* arg) : DataSource(arg) { };

   virtual double getDataA () const = 0;
   virtual std::string getDataB () const = 0;
   ...
}

class WeatherDataSource : public DataSource
{
private:
   // members to store data

public:
   WeatherDataSource(DataSrcImpl* arg) : DataSource(arg) { };

   virtual double getDataC () const = 0;
   virtual std::string getDataD () const = 0;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the most experienced authors, Robert C. Martin suggests to use Proxy or Gateway patterns to deal with API which is prone to frequent changes.
This topic is covered in detail (in particular, access to SQL by means of C#) in chapter No. 34 of his book Agile Software Development, Principles, Patterns, and Practices.

Bridge pattern is usually used in cases where you have multiple hierarchies of classes, and, moreover, multiple interfaces of those hierarchies are prone to changes.

Since you have only one hierarchy (class DataSource with its derivatives PopulationDataSource and WeatherDataSource), Bridge is clearly redundant here.

Gateway pattern:

> Interesting software rarely lives in isolation. Even the purest
> object-oriented system often has to deal with things that aren't
> objects, such as relational data-base tables, CICS transactions, and
> XML data structures.
>
> When accessing external resources like this, you'll usually get APIs
> for them. However, these APIs are naturally going to be somewhat
> complicated because they take the nature of the resource into account.
> Anyone who needs to under-stand a resource needs to understand its API
>
> - whether JDBC and SQL for rela-tional databases or W3C or JDOM for XML. Not only does this make the software harder to understand, it
>   also makes it much harder to change should you shift some data from a
>   relational database to an XML message at some point in the future.
>
> The answer is so common that it's hardly worth stating. Wrap all the
> special API code into a class whose interface looks like a regular
> object. Other objects access the resource through this Gateway, which
> translates the simple method calls into the appropriate specialized
> API.

https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/gateway.html

Comment: Thanks for this answer!

Comment: You're welcome. I've checked your question as upvoted.

Comment: Not sure I expressed it well, so just to clarify: the datasets to retrieve is either population-data, or in another case, weather-data, or something else in a third case. Upon completion, this data should become accessible via an individual interface (getDataA, B vs. getDataC, D).

What I don't get is how to realise the individual-interface part using the Proxy pattern?!
Any hint?

Comment: Here is the implementation for Java: http://staff.cs.utu.fi/staff/jouni.smed/doos_06/material/ProxyAndStairway.pdf

Comment: This is gold. Fantastic!

Comment: just finished reading it. It's funny, cause at the end the author doesn't recommend Proxy :) He closes his discussion with: _"Most applications don’t need proxies. Proxies are a very heavy weight solution. When I see proxy solutions in use, my recommendation in most cases is to take them out and use something simpler. [... use only] in very large systems that undergo frequent schema and/or API thrashing"_

Comment: Here is a ready simple implementation. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30025/A-Simple-Gateway-Proxy-Pattern You have to take into account that Bridge is even more complicated.